# Volume rendering 3D VTK *.vtu UnstructuredGrid file in Paraview

Tags: paraview, vtk

I would like to volumetrically render 3D scalar data in Paraview, and I'm not sure if my inability to do so is incorrect usage of VTK or Paraview.

I have built a *.vtu VTK unstructured grid file containing 2 cells consisting of 10 PolyVertex objects with scalar data associated with each point. These are meant to represent points where the value of the numerical solution is known in space (quadrature points for a finite element, for example). I can load the file into Paraview and view the output as points:

[image]

No problem. However, when I choose the "Volume" representation, rather than points, the points simply disappear, without any volume rendering. I am looking for paraview to linearly interpolate the solution between the points for each cell, the way it would if I provide an Image (Uniform Rectilinear Grid) from a data file:

[image]

However, I seem to be unable to find documentation for how to do this. I imagine the finite element community must commonly render unstructured volume data, so this is surprising.

And the source code used to write out the VTK file in Python:

```
class VtkPolyVertCloud(object):
    """ save each finite element as a set of polyvertices, but lose cell information """

    def __init__(self):

        # geometry
        self.points= vtk.vtkPoints()
        self.grid = vtk.vtkUnstructuredGrid()

        # data
        self.values = vtk.vtkDoubleArray()
        self.values.SetName('point_values_array')

        self.grid.SetPoints(self.points)
        self.grid.GetPointData().SetScalars(self.values)

    def add_polyVertex_cell(self, points, data):
        """
        adds points according to user-supplied numpy arrays, for convenience and to eliminate loops
        in calling code

        @param points: numpy array of 3d point coords -- points.shape = (npoints, 3)
        @param data: scalar-valued data belonging to each point -- data.shape = (npoints,)
        """
        npts = points.shape[0]
        assert(points.shape[1] == 3)             # make sure 3d points passed in
        assert(data.shape[0] == npts) # make sure same number of data, points

        pv = vtk.vtkPolyVertex()
        pv.GetPointIds().SetNumberOfIds(npts)
        for idx, point in enumerate(points):
            pointID = self.points.InsertNextPoint(point)
            pv.GetPointIds().SetId(idx, pointID)
            self.values.InsertNextValue(data[idx])

        self.grid.InsertNextCell(pv.GetCellType(), pv.GetPointIds())
```

and the calling code:

```
def test_vtkPolyVertexCloud_writeToFile():
    """ adds a set of polyvertices meant to represent a finite element """
    pc = vtku.VtkPolyVertCloud()
    points, data = get_random_points_and_data(10)
    pc.add_polyVertex_cell(points, data)
    pc.add_polyVertex_cell(points + 1, data)

    # write
    fn = 'test_PolyVertexCloud.vtu'
    writer = vtk.vtkXMLUnstructuredGridWriter()
    writer.SetFileName(fn)
    writer.SetInputData(pc.grid)
    writer.Write()
```

Update: I took heed of the accepted answer below and did the following:
1. Performed a spatial Delaunay triangulation on each of my finite elements (the numerical solution is known at the nodes of each finite element). The triangulation is fast since there aren't that many points even for a high-order finite element.
2. Constructed a VTK file where each cell is a tetrahedron from the spatial Delaunay triangulation on each element.

Paraview is able to volumetrically plot this.
[image]

Comment: I just tried to render a VTU file in ParaView 5.4.0 64 bits in Linux Mint 18.2 and [it worked](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6395a49f4bcbc7dea89b109db733f796), you can see the image [here](http://tinypic.com/r/huj801/9).

Comment: It seems that your image link is not working. Also, I can't really see how you built the VTK file from that XML file. Did you save each cell as a list of PolyVertex objects? Did you save edges or connectivity? The source code might be more helpful... I've updated the question to include it.

Comment: Weird thing about the image. [Here it is again](http://imgur.com/a/T4gyy).

Comment: Regarding the file creation, I did not write it myself, I just exported an unstructured mesh from ParaView for tests purposes.

Comment: Ok, I can download it and view it myself, so I think there's rather something incorrect with how I'm constructing the *.vtu file. It seems that cells of polyvertices by themselves are not sufficient to do volume rendering, and I don't know why.

Comment: I can output a cube and view that, but in the case of finite elements, there are nodes interior to each element, so I don't want to have to segment them myself and draw them as cubes the *.vtu files. There must be a way to declare an unstructured 3D cell with data points on the inside...

Comment: Can you share your data file?

Comment: Sure, [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c8f79734a5531c1cd1c520b36541c3d6)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63942/discussion-between-nicoguaro-and-user3482876).

Comment: It is not surprising that vtk can't generate a volume rendering for the poly_vertex cell type since there is no topology associated with that type of cell. The way integration point data is normally dealt with is to extrapolate it to the element nodes. Then you can average the values from the different elements connecting to each node. Alternatively, you can define multiple nodes at the same location (one for each element) to represent the discontinuous results (this is the approach used by Deal II, for example).

Comment: @BillGreene, so are you saying that you need to segment each element into VTK cells defined by the finite element nodes? I actually solve for the data exactly AT the element nodes -- the points where the nodal bases are 1, (quadrature free DG scheme) -- but didn't want to have to perform the segmentation within each finite element if there was a way around it.

Comment: Also @BillGreene, if you post that as an answer, I will accept it. It's what I was looking for.

Comment: No, usually the VTK cell type is the same as the FE element topology; there is just one VTK cell for each FE element. Calculating the element-nodal values from the integration point values is more of a data fitting process. I've explained this in more detail in an answer below.

Comment: I should also mention that, supposedly, VTK has some "support" for integration point results, http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_integration_point_support. However, I have looked at the available documents and don't understand how to make it work. If someone does know this and can supply it as an answer to this question, I, for one, would be very interested.

Comment: @BillGreene I'm surprised to hear that each finite element maps to a single VTK cell. If you're going to develop a code with high order elements, you want to plot the high order polynomial at the interior nodes as well, right? Otherwise, I imagine there's bad interp error on element interiors. I think I will perform a spatial Delaunay triangulation on each of my 3D finite elements and write them out as VTK tetrahedral cells. If this is too slow, I'll take the 1VTK cell : 1 Finite Element approach. I'm more interested in high order flow features than preserving cell topology. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, if you have high-order approximation functions in your elements, breaking the element into multiple lower-order elements for visualization (a so-called "view-mesh") is a good approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not surprising that VTK can't generate a volume rendering for the poly_vertex cell type since there is 
no topology associated with that type of cell.

The way finite element integration point results is often dealt with is described below:

It is common in finite element methods to calculate results (e.g. stresses) at the element integration points.
But, typically, for plotting purposes, the result quantities are needed at the nodes. One way to achieve this
is, for each element, to fit a parametric function to the integration point data. Then this function can be
evaluated at each of the element nodes. The exact form of this function depends on the particular element topology and the number of integration points but it is often similar to the shape functions used for the element.

In general, since this procedure is applied element-by-element, the result function will be discontinuous when
more than one element is connected to a node. Most visualization libraries (e.g. VTK) don't directly support
discontinuous nodal results so one of the following approaches is typically used.

1. You can simply average the element-nodal values for all the elements attached to a particular node.
2. You can create "extra" nodes for each element attached to a particular node. These nodes are at the same
   location as the actual node. But having duplicate nodes allows each element to have its own, unique set nodes
   to which results can be attached. This is the approach used by Deal II, for example.